# For loop linux script

Tags: shell-script, shell

1. Ask the user how many papers to grade?
2. Create a for loop that will loop the times necessary for each paper's score to be entered.
3. Ask the user for each score (1-100).
4. count the number of loops
5. At the end of the program display the average score of all the papers

ive done one for a while loop but not sure how to do for loop

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

count=0
papers=0
score=0
grade=0
average=0

read -p " How many papers would you like to grade? " papers

while [ $count -lt $papers ]
do
    read -p " Please enter a score " grade
    score=`expr $score + $grade`
    count=$((count + 1))
done

average=`expr $score / $papers`
echo $average
```

Comment: Im not sure where to even start i struggles with the while loop one is there a way to change the while loop to a for loop?

Comment: i dont know how to make the variables if they are the same way or how to get the loop to go as many times as what number they input

Comment: @bren so what is the error in your script?

Comment: there is no error in that script right there but that is for a while loop..this assignment is asking for a for loop and i have no idea how to do one and cant find much online about them it keeps taking me back to while loop

Comment: sorry this is my first class of linux and scripting so im really new at this

Comment: Bookmark this: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html -- in this case you want [3.2.4.1 Looping Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs). Also https://shellcheck.net to help with syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding the instructions and doing it after my own head (the instructions are bogus anyway as there's no need to ask the user for the number of scores (point 1) if they are to be counted anyway (point 4)).

```
awk 'BEGIN              { printf("Enter scores, one per line, end with Ctrl+D\n") }
     $1 < 1 || $1 > 100 { printf("Invalid score, must be [1,100]\n"); next }
                        { sum += $1; n++ }
     END                { printf("Average: %.2f\n", sum/n) }'
```

Testing:

```
Enter scores, one per line, end with Ctrl+D
0
Invalid score, must be [1,100]
2
3
4
5
99
100
1001
Invalid score, must be [1,100]
Average: 35.50
```

This would make it easy to read in the scores from a file by just using a redirection into the `awk` script.

Same thing in `/bin/sh` (but does not handle non-integer input/result):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Enter scores, one per line, end with Ctrl+D'
while read score; do
    if [ "$score" -lt 1 ] || [ "$score" -gt 100 ]; then
        echo 'Invalid score, must be [1,100]'
    else
        sum=$(( sum + score ))
        n=$(( n + 1 ))
    fi
done

printf 'Average: %d\n' "$(( sum / n ))"
```

If you insist on asking for the number of scores, then you will have to handle out of range scores differently:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf 'Enter the number of scores that you will enter: ' >&2
read nscores

while [ "$nscores" -gt 0 ]; do
    while true; do
        read score
        if [ "$score" -lt 1 ] || [ "$score" -gt 100 ]; then
            echo 'Invalid score, must be [1,100]'
        else
            break
        fi
    done

    sum=$(( sum + score ))
    n=$(( n + 1 ))

    nscores=$(( nscores - 1 ))
done

printf 'Average: %d\n' "$(( sum / n ))"
```

Oops, another `while` loop.

A `for` loop, in shell scripting, is only ever used over an explicit list, such as a list of filenames.  Using a `for` loop in this exercise, if you are writing a shell script to solve it, is not at all necessary.

A reasonable use case where a `for` loop could be used to solve this exercise:

```
#!/bin/sh

for score do
    if [ "$score" -lt 1 ] || [ "$score" -gt 100 ]; then
        printf 'Invalid score (%d), must be [1,100]\n' "$score" >&2
    else
        sum=$(( sum + score ))
        n=$(( n + 1 ))
    fi
done

printf 'Average: %d\n' "$(( sum / n ))"
```

This script would accept the scores on the command line:

```
$ sh ./script.sh 1 20 10 22 3001 20
Invalid score (3001), must be [1,100]
Average: 14
```

Since the list of scores is a static list, it's appropriate to loop over it using a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for this!!what did you think of the answer i accepted would that work for the instructions that i have to follow? i appreciate you helping me out and your input on this it has helped me

Comment: @bren There are two main "issues" with it, depending on how faithful you are to the instructions of the exercise and to current coding standards: (1) It does not test for out-of-range scores, and (2) it (and your code) uses the somewhat antiquated `expr` for integer arithmetics _as well as_ the modern and `bash`-specific `for (( ... )); do` construct (in your code, you also use `$(( ... ))` for arithmetics) (it's the mixing of the two that looks odd to me).

Comment: Thank you for helping me clear this up a little bit im very new to this and do appreciate you taking your time to help me this is my first linux class and scripting and i never have done either so im trying to stay some what faithful to the instructions but i do understand what you are telling me about mixing old with modern

Answer (score 0):

You have done almost everything I just changed your while loop into for loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
declare -i score=0
declare -i grade=0
read -p " How many papers would you like to grade? " papers
for ((count=0; count<$papers; count++)) ;do
 read -p " Please enter a score " grade
 score=$(expr $score + $grade)
 done
average=$(expr $score / $papers)
echo $average
```

Comment: that is all you had to do was change the while to a for? and did u have to change the parentheses?

Comment: @bren yes both are same, while loop doesn't provide the increment or decrement part.

Comment: thank you so much ive been trying to look into this for 4 days now and found this website and decided to post if anybody would help me and you have cleared things up for me i really appreciate it

Comment: @bren but I think the code you provided has some problems in it.

Comment: are there any websites or anything you can recommend for helping me learn more about linux and scripting or have you just been doing it for awhile?

Comment: what problems do you see in that code? when i run the while loop code i provided everything worked fine for me but you would know better than me i feel if you see any errors

Comment: ohh your fine i really appreciate your time and help on this it has helped me a lot.  have you been doing linux and scripting for awhile is there anything you can recommend to help me ? seems like something once i keep doing it more and more it will get easier and more understanding

Comment: that does solve it for me im going to input the code and see if it runs...thank you again i really do appreciate it.

Comment: @bren sorry missed something and now fixed it, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already accepted an answer, but I'll provide a slightly different perspective. If you need to iterate over integers in a bash script, you can use `seq` Type

```
$ man seq
```

in a console and read how it works.

Example oneliner:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

instead of `echo $i` you'll just have your the logic for your task

Comment: thank you for that input i didnt know that...what did you think of the answer i accepted?I am very new at linux and shell script

Comment: the answer you accepted is just a slightly different approach. @Debian_yadav manually incremented a variable, this is closer to C style, I used a generator instead (seq as in sequence generates a list of integers), this is rather close to functional programming. as long as there are no explicit restrictions on the way you must complete the assignment, I think the choice is up to you and it's just a matter of personal taste. if you had the requirement to not use any external tool, then you couldn't use seq